# Java selecting words from a string

Tags: java, parsing

HI Everyone. I'm sorry for this embarrassingly newbie question but I cannot seem to figure out the command to do it. I'm okay with python and had a script in jython that I'm convering to pure java(and learning along the way).

I have a string: `Java is really cool`

I know how to strip the string to get the final result: `really cool`

but i'm not sure the command to do it in java.  I found commands in java to do it specifically by text but I want to use a space as a deliminator and get the words.

Can someone tell me what java command to use? I would want to be able either remove the first two words and/or specifically select the words I want.

Thanks,

Comment: What are the rules that would decide which words to extract?  Without rules there is no code. Otherwise String#split(...) allows you to split Strings based on most any delimiter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`String.split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String s = "Java is really cool";
String words[] = s.split(" ");
String firstTwo = words[0] + "  " + words[1]; // first two words
String lastTwo = words[words.length - 2] + " "
        + words[words.length - 1]; // last two words
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I was able to get this far but how do I get everything from the second words onwards..in python it would be words[2:] but not sure how to do it in java.

Comment: @Lostsoul: Might just have to create a new array, and use a good-ol' `for` loop to grab words from 2 onward.  words[2:] is just syntactic sugar for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [`String.split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method

Answer (score 2):

```
String foo = "java is really cool";
String bar[] = foo.split(" ");
```

this will separate all of the words into an array.