# Android Multiple line in TextView

Tags: android-layout, android

[image]![Image][2] I have tried this code

```
private static class MySpan implements LineHeightSpan {
        private final int height;

        MySpan(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int spanstartv, int v,
                FontMetricsInt fm) {
            fm.bottom += height;
            fm.descent += height;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(tv);

        tv.setText("Lines:\n", BufferType.EDITABLE);
        appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 1 = 40\n", 40);
        appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 2 = 30\n", 30);
        appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 3 = 20\n", 20);
        appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 4 = 10\n", 10);

    }

    private void appendLine(Editable text, String string, int height) {
        final int start = text.length();
        text.append(string);
        final int end = text.length();
        text.setSpan(new MySpan(height), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

I am trying to set padding between lines of **TextView**, but not able to do it.
How to differentiate multiple lines in TextView ,if i set background color of TextView. Please point me in the right direction. I want to differentiate color between two line . as u can see that in this image it is not working ..
I want some thing like 1st image while i am getting output like 2nd image..
Please help me..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLineSpacing(2, 1); // UPDATE HERE
    setContentView(tv);

    tv.setText("Lines:\n", BufferType.EDITABLE);
    appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 1 = 40\n", 40);
    appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 2 = 30\n", 30);
    appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 3 = 20\n", 20);
    appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "Line 4 = 10\n", 10);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , but i did'nt get result ,I have edited my question please refer it.. reply me back

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split lines and display them in different color then refer to following links.

[Split text from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785094/java-selecting-words-from-a-string)

[Apply color to specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually  I want to set background color for text and if text is multi line then i want to make separation that on line can be seen..