# Select a part of TextView text

Tags: android, textview

I want to grab Text when user click on the `TextView`

For Example :

```
TextView string = "this is a test for android and textView"
```

When user click on textview in `android` position grab `android`
Anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: Do you create the TextView by code or in a XML ? Can you provide us more code ?

Comment: poor english explain  ur question

Comment: my purpose is when user click on textview(Textview include long string) grab clicked text... a little like OCR but here i a textview not image .

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
text.onClickListner(this);


@Override
public void onClick() {
    String textOnTextView = text.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an onClick listener to the textview, make it final and then get its text.

```
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String getTxt = txt.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: He don't want all the text. Just part of the text where the user touches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split lines and display them in different color then refer to following links.

[Split text from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785094/java-selecting-words-from-a-string)

[Apply color to specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview)

Answer (score 0):

A button has onClick , I dont think that a TextView has onClick so that a user clicks it.

Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: All View got onClickListener : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html. So yes TextView does got onClick

Comment: all views got onClickListener as Plumillon said, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select part of text, try to use `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for your need. But only one step to solution.

Use `setTextIsSelectable(boolean)` or the `TextView_textIsSelectable` XML attribute to make the TextView selectable (text is not selectable by default).

Using following code, I managed to get selected text as String. You need to first select string by dragging over it.
 
NB: you need minimum **API 11** to use `setTextIsSelectable(boolean)`

```
TextView t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t1.setTextIsSelectable(true);// IMPORTANT
        t1.setText("This is Android program");
        t1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    int start=t1.getSelectionStart();
                    int end=t1.getSelectionEnd();
                    String sub=t1.getText().subSequence(start, end).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sub, 1).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```