# How get the first letter of TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I have not found documentation on how I can get the first letter of a value in a `TextView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very easy,

```
String strTextview = textView.getText().toString();
strTextView = strTextView.substring(0,1);
```

Alternatively you can try following way too

```
char firstCharacter = textView.getText().toString().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the first letter you'll have to make this call:

```
char firstCharacter = myTextView.getText().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the method from below. Provide the string from TextView as the parameter.

```
public String firstStringer(String s) {
            String str= s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), 1));
            return str;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
   String frstLetter = tv.getText().substring(0, 1);
```

Comment: NP, Great answer, +1 from myside.

Comment: Sorry, if there are two words in the `TextView`, how do I get the first letter of the second word?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785094/java-selecting-words-from-a-string[link] This shows the use of String.split() which allows you to separate a string into different parts

Answer (score 1):

it is simple. To retrieve the Text from the TextView you have to use `getText().toString();`

```
String textViewContent = textViewInstance.getText().toString();
```

and the first letter `textViewContent.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the content of the string from TextView:

```
 String content = textView.getText().toString();
```

To fetch the first character

```
char first = content.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String value = text.getText().toString();
 String firstTen = value.substring(0, 1);
```